# strange routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have some really strange rails behavior:

**The routes.rb:**

```
resources :transactions, except: :show
```

**The relevant output of rake routes:**

```
       transactions GET    /transactions(.:format)                  transactions#index
                    POST   /transactions(.:format)                  transactions#create
    new_transaction GET    /transactions/new(.:format)              transactions#new
   edit_transaction GET    /transactions/:id/edit(.:format)         transactions#edit
        transaction PUT    /transactions/:id(.:format)              transactions#update
                    DELETE /transactions/:id(.:format)              transactions#destroy
```

**The code in the view:**

```
<% if ( current_page?( new_transaction_path ) || current_page?( edit_transaction_path ) ) %>
  # Do something in here
<% end %>
```

**The error:**

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 20ms

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"transactions"}):
```

It works when I remove the `|| current_page?( edit_transaction_path )` part.

Did I something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: try to pass the transaction object to edit_transaction_path: `edit_transaction_path(@transaction)`

Comment: But I do not always have a transaction object... Is there a more general way? I just want to check if I edit ANY transaction object...

Comment: `current_page?( :action => "edit", :controller => "transactions" )` seems to work.
@antonk: Do you want to post that as an answer? I would accept it, you  gave me the idea that it ID is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to pass the transaction object to edit_transaction_path: `edit_transaction_path(@transaction)`

`current_page?( :action => "edit", :controller => "transactions")` - yes, this is the best way, I believe.